# Same Policy but different required parameter for each action method

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-authorization, policy-based-security

In a `.Net core Webapi 2.1` project, I have a tons of action methods.
All action methods should be authorized against the same policy (named `FooPolicy`) but with a different required argument.
Based on Microsoft's docs: [Policy-based-Authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1)
One way would be to declare a tons of policies based on different input argument:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("FooPolicy1", policy =>policy.Requirements.Add(new FooRequirement(1)));
    options.AddPolicy("FooPolicy2", policy =>policy.Requirements.Add(new FooRequirement(2)));
    options.AddPolicy("FooPolicy3", policy =>policy.Requirements.Add(new FooRequirement(3)));
    //... May be 30 more same policies here ...
});
```

As i earlier mentioned, only different part is in `new FooRequirement(diffArgs)`. The other challenge for this solution would be to add each `FooPolicy` on it's corresponding action method and you may miss a couple of theme:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy1")]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo1(...) {...}

[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy2")]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo2(...) {...}

[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy3")]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo3(...) {...}
...List still goes on...
```

**Is there any solution like:** declare a policy once but use it with different instance of `FooRequirement` (which is of type `IAuthorizationHandler`)? like so:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("FooPolicy", policy =>policy.Requirements.Add(?));
});
```

And on the action methods:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy", required = new FooRequirement(1))]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo1(...) {...}

[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy", required = new FooRequirement(2))]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo2(...) {...}

[Authorize(Policy = "FooPolicy", required = new FooRequirement(3))]
public IActionResult ActionMethodFoo3(...) {...}
```

The main idea is to *declare policy once*. Two recent code blocks are psudo-code, Does any body knows practical solution with similar concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could implement your own `IAuthorizationFilter`

1. custom `IAuthorizationFilter`

   ```
   public class CustomAuthorize : IAuthorizationFilter         
    {
           private readonly int _input;

   public CustomAuthorize(int input)
   {
       _input = input;
   }

   public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
   {
       //custom validation rule
       if (_input == 1)
       {
           context.Result = new ForbidResult();
       }
   }
   }
   ```
2. Custom `CustomAuthorizeAttribute`

   ```
   public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : TypeFilterAttribute
   {
   public CustomAuthorizeAttribute(int input) : base(typeof(CustomAuthorize))
   {
       Arguments = new object[] { input };
   }
   }
   ```
3. Use

   ```
   [CustomAuthorizeAttribute(1)]
   public IActionResult About()
   ```